# Galera first node won´t start

Tags: mariadb, galera

Ive been trying to set up a Galera Cluster. Since Im new to Linux I used the guide from mariadb ([Link](https://blog.mariadb.org/installing-mariadb-galera-cluster-on-debian-ubuntu/)). I made everything as it stands there but the first node just won´t start when I use the command "service mysql start --wsrep-new-cluster". Im always getting the error:

```
Failed to open channel 'cluster1' at 'gcomm://10.1.0.11,10.1.0.12,10.1.0.13': -110 (Connection timed out)
```

My config file on all three nodes looks like this:

```
#mysql settings
binlog_format=ROW
default-storage-engine=innodb
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2
query_cache_size=0
query_cache_type=0
bind-address=0.0.0.0
#galera settings
wsrep_provider=/usr/lib/galera/libgalera_smm.so
wsrep_cluster_name="cluster1"
wsrep_cluster_address="gcomm://10.1.0.11,10.1.0.12,10.1.0.13"
wsrep_sst_method=rsync
```

Comment: Do you find any way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Change MySQL config (remove IP addresses from gcomm://) at start-up of 1st cluster node or start cluster with --wsrep_cluster_address="gcomm://", that should do the trick.
Then you can add those IP address back into config - so that current 1st node can rejoin running cluster.

Haven't looked into it deep, but looks like option "--wsrep-new-cluster" is not handled correctly, because 1st node is still looking for live nodes, so you must temporarily remove all members of the cluster on 1st node (all IPs from cluster_address field).
Start all other nodes normally.
Newer OS versions use "bootstrap" instead "--wsrep-new-cluster".

My versions: Debian 9.4.0, MariaDB 10.1.26, Galera 25.3.19-2.